# Should I maintain a JavaScript file with routes as variables or is it not safe / bad practice?

Tags: javascript, variables, routes

Our team has been working on a website these last months, but we are quite new at web development.

We have programmed our frontend with vanilla JavaScript, our code handles some common tasks like sending http requests, passing parameters to a form, etc.

Since we have to deal with different endpoints and routes, and often have to switch between two different domains, we decided to put all the routes that are used by our JavaScript code (not used in HTML) in a single file as variables so it would be easier to change them while we were working. An example:

```
const SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://localhost:5000/";

// End points
const CONTACT_GET_ROUTE = SERVER_ADDRESS + "contact/getById/";
const CONTACT_GET_LIST_ROUTE = SERVER_ADDRESS + "contact/list";
const CONTACT_POST_ROUTE = SERVER_ADDRESS + "contact/post";
const CONTACT_PUT_ROUTE = SERVER_ADDRESS + "contact/put";
```

This was made only for our comfort, but we are reaching the end of the development process and we are not sure whether we should keep this file or manually replace the routes before obfuscating. Our main concern are security issues, but we are also worried about the possibility of this being considered bad practice. Are we doing the right thing?

Comment: Have you hardwired the `localhost`? That would be a problem on production.

Comment: You might want to look into [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) objects instead of plain strings but I wouldn't say it's bad practice exactly.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! In first place, we haven't hardwired our localhost, we set it on a virtual machine for testing. About the URL objects, I will look into them, they might become handy in a future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Our main concern are security issues, but we are also worried about the possibility of this being considered bad practice.

The #1 most important thing in security is to understand your attacker and how they can attack you ... in other words, you want to imagine the most clever and malicious child you can (think Eric Cartman on the TV show South Park), and then think "what could that child do on my site".

If you try that exercise, I think what you will find is ... there is nothing that malicious child can possibly do just by knowing your client's routes.  In fact, even if you *don't* put those routes into variables, if the attacker were to use the browser developer tools they could *still* see your routes in the Net tab.

So in short, this is not a security concern.  But for a larger understanding of web security, I *strongly* recommend reading the [OWASP Top Ten](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) attacks, because it's essentially the smartest people in web security listing the top ten ways that your site could be attacked (but it's also not a mountain of reading: you just have to understand ten attacks and you're done).  It's the stuff on that list that you *should* worry about first and foremost.

P.S. Keeping routes in variables also not a bad practice either.  To the contrary, keeping your code clean and understandable is always a good thing!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the resources! We won't worry about it then. I will read the article, since we are testing for security flaws too.